# How to remove the sensitive information before @github.com to sanitize it correctly using Python 3.9 and/or regex?

Tags: python, regex

I need to include a username and token in a github url to access a private repo on github.

After accessing it, I need to sanitize it to obtain the clean version.

The input pattern is `https://{username}:{token}@github.com/{repo_owner}/{repo-name}`

The output pattern i want is `https://github.com/{repo_owner}/{repo-name}`

For e.g. I am given this

`https://usernameabc:token1234@github.com/abc/easy-as-123`

I want this

`https://github.com/abc/easy-as-123`

How do I do this with Python? I am okay to use regex

### What I use that works

I am using this

```
def sanitize_github_url(github_url_with_username_token):
    github_url_with_username_token = github_url_with_username_token.lower()
    index = github_url_with_username_token.find("github.com/", 0)
    suffix = github_url_with_username_token[index:]
    return f"https://{suffix}"
```

And it works for my purposes. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What details and clarity? I even included the code i wrote as workaround. I disagree with the close flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd prefer to not use regex in this scenario, and instead use a url manipulation library like [furl](https://github.com/gruns/furl)

eg:

```
from furl import furl

url = furl("https://usernameabc:token1234@github.com/abc/easy-as-123")
url.password = None
url.username = None

print(str(url))
```

output:

```
https://github.com/abc/easy-as-123
```

Comment: Thank you, this works and without using regex. I love it

Answer (score 0):

Use regex with backward and forward lookaround.

```
raw = r'https://usernameabc:token1234@github.com/abc/easy-as-123'
re.sub("(?<=https://).*?(?=github.com)", "", raw)
```